# cite journals using first authors name with the year of article?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

So I have journals cited in my .bib file. However I want to cite these using their names and the year it was published e.g.
"Smith et al (2020) disucsses"

I have tried these but not managed to do anything, it just comes up with a "?"

```
~\citeauthor{name of journal}
~\citeyear{name of journal}
```

Here is a citation:

```
@ARTICLE{Healthcare4.0,  author={Wehde, Mark},  journal={IEEE Engineering Management Review},   title={Healthcare 4.0},   year={2019},  volume={47},  number={3},  pages={24-28},  doi={10.1109/EMR.2019.2930702}}
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\graphicspath{ {./images/} } 

\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document} 

~\citeauthor{Healthcare4.0}
~\citeyear{Healthcare4.0}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to change to the appropriate bibliography style. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You say "it just comes up with a '?'". Did you run `bibtex`?

Answer (score 1):

The ancient `plain` bibliography style can only produce numeric-style citation call-outs. If you want to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, but are otherwise satisfied with how `plain` formats the bibliographic entries, I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the options `authoryear` and `round` and (b) switch the bibliography style from `plain` to `plainnat`. As an additional bonus from switching from `plain` to `plainnat`, you can also use fields such as `url` and `doi`.

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

After you make these changes, be sure to run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- in order to fully propagate the effects of these changes.

Comment: is it possible to use this bibliography style along with another in the same document?

Comment: @user18372316 - Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if it's possible to employ 2 (or more) bibliography styles simultaneously, in one and the same document? If so, the answer is "no".